# Sign In With Google Button Padding in iframe

Tags: iframe, google-signin, padding

I'm using the Sign In With Google Button using this library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-oauth/google).

The button is being rendered in an iframe.

**How do I get rid of the padding (green portion in the picture) in one of the divs (in the iframe)?**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Applying this style on the iframe helped:

```
iframe {
    color-scheme: normal;
}
```

Comment: I searched for hours and this is the simplest and best solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't, Google controls the render of the iframe
you can use useGoogleLogin and create your custom login button if you want to have dark theme

Comment: But if I create a custom login button, does that mean I won't be able to use the "personalized button" (https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/personalized-button)?